# Mocking MessegePostProcessor Interface in JmsTemplate

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-jms

I'm new in *Mockito* and I'm facing an issue regarding a stubbing argument mismatch.

so far I thought this would works fine since in my implementation *jmsTemplate* is a depedency of *jmsTemplateService* and everything is injected via @Mock and @InjectMocks

and theoretically I'm mocking the execution of the invoked dependent method

```
convertAndSend(String destinationName, final Object message, final MessagePostProcessor postProcessor)
```

main part of test

```
Message message = Mockito.mock(Message.class);

MessagePostProcessor messagePostProcessor = (x) -> message;

doNothing()
           .when(jmsTemplate)
           .convertAndSend(queue, obj, messagePostProcessor);

jmsTemplateService.sendMessage(queue, obj);
```

but mockito throws a stubbing argument mismatch error which actually made me understand I'm not stubbing correctly.

```
- this invocation of 'convertAndSend' method:
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(
    "queueA",
     Obj(),
  com.example.JmsTemplateService$$Lambda$383/0x0000000800dd9440@5fb7183b
);
    -> at com.example.JmsTemplateService.sendMessage(JmsTemplateService.java:64)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(
    "queueA",
   Obj(),
   com.example.JmsTemplateServiceTest$$Lambda$382/0x0000000800ddb360@74ad8d05
);
```

it seems the last parameter is the actual problem but I don't know how to capture it without mocking the jmsTemplate dependencies too.

this is the current implementation of the *JmsTemplateService.sendMessage(String queue, Obj obj)*

```
 public void sendMessage(String queue, Object obj) {
        
      try {
           jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, obj, message -> {
           //do stuffs before sending the message
           });
      }catch (Exception e) {
       //handle exception
    }
```

any hint of what could be wrong in mocking the *convertAndSend* method?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems the last parameter is the actual problem but I don't know how to capture it without mocking the jmsTemplate dependencies too.

Actually, you are mocking `jmsTemplate`, otherwise it'd throw an exception because `jmsTemplate` variable is not a mock.

```
doNothing()
       .when(jmsTemplate) <- a mock is expected to be used here
       .convertAndSend(queue, obj, messagePostProcessor);
```

You're right that the last parameter is the actual problem since different instances are being used.

The first instance is defined by your lambda in the test:

```
MessagePostProcessor messagePostProcessor = (x) -> message;
```

And the second one is defined with the other lambda when you perform the call to `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(..., ..., message -> {...})`

Posibly you're getting that error because you're verifying that the `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(...)` was called with the params you defined in the tests.
Something like:

```
verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(queue, obj, messagePostProcessor);
```

What you can do is expect `any()` as a 3rd argument in that verify, and expect something like `ArgumentsMatchers.eq(queue)` and `ArgumentsMatchers.eq(obj)` as other arguments:

```
verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(ArgumentsMatchers.eq(queue), ArgumentsMatchers.eq(obj), any());
```

---

#### Update: possible solution to test the dependencies inside the MessagePostProcessor

```
class JmsTemplateServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Mock
    private Message message;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<String> queueCaptor;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<String> messageCaptor;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<MessagePostProcessor> messagePostProcessorArgumentCaptor;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testJmsTemplateWorksWithCorrectMessagePostProcessor() throws JMSException {
        // Given
        String destinationQueue = "test-queue";
        String testMessage = "test message";

        // When
        doNothing().when(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(destinationQueue, testMessage, message -> message);

        // Inline dummy implementation that adds an element to a list defined in this test scope
        List<String> stateCustomDependency = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomDependency customDependency = () -> stateCustomDependency.add("Got executed!");

        // Performs service call
        JmsTemplateService jmsTemplateService = new JmsTemplateService(jmsTemplate, customDependency);
        jmsTemplateService.sendMessage(destinationQueue, testMessage);

        // Then verify the service actually invokes the jmsTemplate and capture the arguments passed to it
        verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(queueCaptor.capture(), messageCaptor.capture(), messagePostProcessorArgumentCaptor.capture());

        // Verify values of queue and message
        assertEquals(destinationQueue, queueCaptor.getValue());
        assertEquals(testMessage, messageCaptor.getValue());

        // Verify the MessagePostProcessor instantiated inside the service invokes the lambda dependencies
        MessagePostProcessor messagePostProcessorToVerify = messagePostProcessorArgumentCaptor.getValue();
        messagePostProcessorToVerify.postProcessMessage(message);
        assertEquals(1, stateCustomDependency.size()); // Ensure the CustomDependency was invoked
        assertEquals("Got executed!", stateCustomDependency.get(0)); // Ensure the right String was added by CustomDependency
    }
}
```

In case you also need to call some method on Message object, you'll have to add statements like `when(message.someMethod(...)).thenReturn(...)`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Leo :). Well, if I verify I would definitely use the anymatcher for the 3rd parameter but still I’m struggling to verify the code inside the lambda, even mocking what I should happen I can’t jump into that block (e.g. the debugger does not get inside :( ) and more over I got no clue have to achieve something like this. Sadly this is legacy code and this seems to be a such a tricky thing to do )

Comment: Mmm, actually, the code inside the lambda will never get executed because you're mocking the `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(...)` which is who actually performs the `postProcessor.postProcessMessage(msg)` call.

Comment: That was my concern when I put hands on, a consequence of dealing with legacy code  hence I’m afraid I should push to change the implementation in order to make it testable.

Comment: When you say that "this is legacy code", are you referring to `JmsTemplateService` or an specific implementation of `JmsTemplate`?
What I understand you're testing is `JmsTemplateService`, not `JmsTemplate`.
So, I think you shouldn't worry about the lambda is executed or not.
But if what you want is to test the `JmsTemplate`, then I think it should be done in a separate test where the target is actually the `JmsTemplate` implementation :)

Comment: I refer to the `JmsTemplateService` which has been already refactored by me, the previous implementation was a giant all in one method not testable at all. so mainly I've been able to split this giant in different layers and now it's like a puzzle, dependencies are easy to replace apart this part I posted here.

Comment: @Maxuel I've edited my answer with a possible solution (maybe not the best one by it works) to test the dependencies used inside the `MessagePostProcessor`. Please check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `MessagePostProcessor` you use to stub the `JmsTemplate` is different from the actual instance that is passed to the `JmsTemplate` when the test method is executed.

The `MessagePostProcessor` passed to the mocked `JmsTemplate` is a new instance that is created internally inside the test method while the one you use for stubbing is created outside the test method. They are apparently two different instances.

Since `convertAndSend()` in `JmsTemplate` return void , there is nothing for you to stub. You can simply verify if it is executed correctly with the expected parameters after executing the test method. Something likes :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class JmsTemplateServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private JmsTemplateService jmsTemplateService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        jmsTemplateService = new JmsTemplateService(jmsTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void convertAndSendTest() {
        Object someObject = ....;
        jmsTemplateService.sendMessage("queueA", someObject);
        verify(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend(eq("queueA"), eq(someObject), any());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank your for the feedback! Actually I was able to verify the convertAndSend() method but not what is being executed inside the MessagePostProcessor which is actually the most important part since I invoke other dependencies and I need to verify that those dependencies have been called with the right parameters.

Comment: It you want to verify the codes of the `MessagePostProcessor` inside your test methods interact with other dependencies correctly , also mock these dependencies and verify on them.

Comment: Indeed probably I’m not interacting correctly with the other dependencies but so far all the dependencies are mocked and correctly initialiased as I could see how the constructor is invoked injecting as expected. Still, what I don’t understand is how it could be possible to jump with the debugger to the code inside the lambda even though the dependencies are “correctly” invoked

Comment: Are you sure ? As you are mocking `convertAndSend()` , the codes of the `MessagePostProcessor` (i.e lambda) should not execute. Also if you want to test the code the lambda code , consider to refactor it to a separate `MessagePostProcessor` class and write another separate test class for it. For   `JmsTemplateServiceTest` , you just focus on testing on `JmsTemplateService` (e.g if it interacts with its dependencies correctly etc.) but not focusing on testing on if its dependencies work as expected which should be done in other tests

Comment: at the end, I decided to split it even more and create a service in which I can inject and mock the `MessagePostProcessor`. it turns to be the easiest and cleanest solution :)
Thank to every one for the support! long life to this community!